# typescript debugging in visual studio 2015 no longer works with Angular 2 2.0.0-rc.1

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular

After upgrading to Angular 2 rc1 typescript debugging in visual studio 2015 stopped working.  I added in the meta tag as in previous versions but this causes all other kinds of problems now about 'require' is undefined.  Has anyone been able to get this working yet?

here is my system.config.js file

```
(function (global) {

// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
    'app': 'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular'
};

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename 
// and/or no extension
var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
};
var meta = {
    '*.js': { scriptLoad: true } //this allows TS debugging in VS
};

var packageNames = [
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/router-deprecated',
  '@angular/testing',
  '@angular/upgrade',
];

// add package entries for angular packages in 
// the form '@angular/common':    {   main: 'index.js', 
// defaultExtension: 'js' }
packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

var config = {
    meta: meta,
    map: map,
    packages: packages
}

// filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before
// we register it.
if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

System.config(config);

})(this);
```

Comment: I can't be the only one noticing this am I?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to run in cmd the following command for your project folder

```
>tsc
```

but make sure first you've got the typescript compiler installed

```
$ npm install typescript-compiler
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got our angular2 debugging from VS2015 working again using Gulp. Have you tried Gulp ? The following instruction was helpful:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1087605/Angular-typescript-configuration-and-debugging-for.

Basically, what I did was:

- add gulp into package.json

  ```
               "devDependencies": {    
                    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
                     ...
                }
  ```
- add gulpfile.js into the root directory of the project (see codeProject link above for content)
- add meta when calling Sytem.config

  ```
     System.config({
      meta: {
          '*.js': {
              scriptLoad: true
          }
      },
      packages: {
          app: {
              format: 'register',
              defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
      }
  });
  ```

  - re-run "npm install"
  - Follow the intstruction: "Right mouse click gulpfile.js and select Task Runner Explorer. Right mouse click moveToLibs and select Run"